# Facebook Graph API, return search results for verified accounts only

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to search the Facebook Graph API and return results only for verified accounts. I tried:

`search?q=woody_allen&type=page&is_verified=true`

But that still returns all possible results.

I'd also be willing to try to find pages like this one https://www.facebook.com/pages/Woody-Allen/104025746302510

But that page doesn't seem to show up in the page results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it (using ruby):

```
results=HTTParty.get(base_url + "search?q=woody_allen&type=page&" + access_token)

results["data"].each do |r| 
  v=HTTParty.get("https://graph.facebook.com/" + r['id'].to_s + "?fields=is_verified&" + access_token)
  if v["is_verified"] == true 
    puts "#{r['id'].to_s} this is verified"
  end
end
```